# Current user login name in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to define a display template for one of my site columns by using XSLT. One of the things I would need is the loginname (DOMAIN\user) of the currently logged in user.

There's one way described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx), using parameterbindings. But I'm trying to make this as generic as possible, so setting the parameterbindings for each web part is unrealistic.

I found a way to get the user's ID on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff806158(v=office.14).aspx). And, based on the [ddwrt namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(v=office.11).aspx#officesharepointddwrt_aboutddwrtnamespacereference) I discovered the method **UserLookup**

So I tried the following snippet:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup,($Userid,'ID')" />
```

But unfortunately this just returns a blank string. Where am I going wrong? If my current approach won't work, what other way is there?

Comment: You can try to use <xsl:value-of select="$UserID" /> to display the current username.

Comment: I tried that but got an XslLoadException that the parameter 'UserID' doesn't exist. 'Userid' does exist, but that's the ID of the user (the number), not the loginname.

Comment: This might help you:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx

Comment: You might have to add the parameter binding; see my answer below.

Comment: I've tried this - it can work in a `DispForm.aspx` without issue, but it doesn't work in `fldtypes.xsl` - I think because the regular list-views do not include the parameter binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a couple things.

First, you might need to make sure your xsl connector has this parameter binding:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
```

And make sure this is in there:

```
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
```

Then, add this parameter to give your xsl access to that value:

```
<xsl:param name="UserID"/>
```

Now, in your xsl, you can do this:

```
UserID: <xsl:value-of select="$UserID"/><br />
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup(string($UserID) ,'ID')" /><br />
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup(string($UserID) ,'EMail')" />
```

[I figured this out from this page](http://www.benprins.net/2012/07/30/presence-and-user-profile-url-with-xslt/) and [from here, especially](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/getting-the-current-user-in-sharepoint-xslt).  I tried this in a custom `DispForm.aspx` page (because it was an easy place to test) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup(string($Userid) ,'ID')" />
```

You had "," after UserLookup.

Answer (score 0):

I use a different way to do the same thing.
I use the _spPageContextInfo (an object that is possible to return in every sp page).

Example for returning name of Current User:

```
<script type="text/javascript"​>  
var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;  
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";             
var requestHeaders = { "accept" : ​"application/json;odata=verbose" };   
$.ajax({
        url : requestUri,
        contentType :"application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers : requestHeaders,
        success : onSuccess,
        error : onError   }); 
function onSuccess(data, request)
{  ​
var loginName = data.d.Title;
    alert(loginName);   
}  
function onError(error) 
{
     alert("error");   
} ​​
</script>
```

More about _spPageContextInfo:

[Click Here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx)