# How to get current user email id or login name in XSLT?

Tags: sharepoint-online, xslt

I am using office 365, and trying to get current user email id or login name in XSLT. A similar question is asked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114053/current-user-login-name-in-xslt). How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint offers a couple of ways by which we can obtain the current user using XSLT, check the below links solution is provided there

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/getting-the-current-user-in-sharepoint-xslt

http://www.benprins.net/2012/07/30/presence-and-user-profile-url-with-xslt/

http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-current-user-name-using-xsl-and-parameterbinding/